# Custom cache not caching querystring

Tags: asp.net, caching, query-string, global-asax, outputcache

I'm using custom cache on a page, leaving a timestamp to follow cached versions.

I have

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="1200" VaryByParam="None" VaryByCustom="myCache" Location="ServerAndClient" %>
```

on the page, and the code-behind of Global.asax has (simplified)

```
Public Overrides Function GetVaryByCustomString(context As HttpContext, arg As String) As String
If (arg = "myCache") Then
   If context.Request.QueryString("Type").ToString() = "1" Then Return "cache-1"
   If context.Request.QueryString("Type").ToString() = "2" Then Return "cache-2"
   If context.Request.Cookies("Type").Value = "1" Then Return "cache-1"
   Return "cache-2"
End If
```

`cache-2` is default state for when no querystring request has been made and cookie doesn't say otherwise. The page saves the cookie with value of `Type`.

When I call the page with either `?Type=1` or `?Type=2` the page isn't saved to cache - each refresh the timestamp changes.

I found that if I call the page **without** the `Type` parameter cache is saved and then exists when I call the page with the parameter as well.

Is there an explanation? Moreover - in Global.asax I couldn't access `Response` object or file system to log what's happening. Is there a way?

**UPDATE**

e.g. calling `<url>?Type=1`, then `<url>` gives me cache for next calls of `<url>?Type=1`, but gives **same cache** for `<url>?Type=2`.

**UPDATE**

I now have `Return "cache" & context.Request.QueryString("Type")`. While sending a request without `Type` in the querystring gives a cached version of the page, sending `Type` does not cache, though the result (`cache1` or `cache2`) is the same and page should get cached.

**follow up**
I've found sending `Type=3`, or anything besides `1` and `2` does cache the page as desired. `Page_Load` acts upon values `1` & `2` - could there be any connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411180/asp-net-outputcache-and-cookies) seem to explain a lot. Workaround is a separate question.