# Application_EndRequest not finding Session

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

I'm trying to set a cookie in Application_EndRequest in Global.asax.vb as suggested in [ASP.NET OutputCache and Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411180/asp-net-outputcache-and-cookies/13592488#13592488)

I've written the following code, cookie gets `ERROR` value.

Why isn't session available?

```vb
Sub Application_EndRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    If Not context.Session Is Nothing Then
        context.Response.Cookies("T").Value = context.Session("T")
    Else
        context.Response.Cookies("T").Value = "ERROR"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 16):

The session does not exist anymore in the `Application_EndRequest` event.

`Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute` is called after the code from your application is executed but before the `SessionState` is released.

```vb
Sub Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
    If Not context.Session Is Nothing Then
        context.Response.Cookies("T").Value = context.Session("T")
    Else
        context.Response.Cookies("T").Value = "ERROR"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm looking for something that executes after each HTTP request, I thought `Application_EndRequest` does that. Session shouldn't be released between requests, only at the end of the session.

Comment: It's not the session that is released, but the SessionState, it's control is returned to the server. This event is fired for each request, just after you handled the request (aka "your code").